# Using PyMongo with Public SSL Key

Tags: python, mongodb, ssl, pymongo

I'm trying out the hosted MongodDB+ beta from Compose.io, which supports SSL connections. It provides a public SSL key, and to connect from the command line you use the following arguments:

```
$ mongo -ssl -sslCAFile example.pem example.dblayer.com:10373/admin -u user -p pass
```

I need to access my DB from a Python script using PyMongo, but I'm not sure how to translate the above syntax to MongoClient connection arguments; I'm only familiar with connecting without SSL, i.e.

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://<user>:<pass>@example.dblayer.com:10373/admin')
```

Comment: Have you tried these examples? http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/tls.html

Comment: I haven't seen this doc - I've been searching within the PyMongo documentation - so thank you for sharing! This is exactly what I need!

Comment: Cool! Note that that is for the current release of pymongo--examples from the previous one here: http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.8/examples/authentication.html

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

```
import os
import ssl
from pymongo import MongoClient

mongoDB_uri = 'mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s' % ("user_name", "password", 
"host_name", "db_name")

client = MongoClient(mongoDB_uri,
        ssl=True,
        ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
        ssl_ca_certs="/path/to/cert.pem")

db_conn = client["db_name"]
print(db_conn.collection_name.find_one())
```

Comment: Please refer these links for creating mongo connection string https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/ ,  for MongoClient http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/tls.html   let me know if you are looking for a specific thing